# Is constant acceleration the same relative to other objects at all velocities?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, acceleration, observers, time-dilation

If you are accelerating at a constant rate of 10 $m/s^2$, will you see things around you move at 10 $m/s$ faster every second, even when approaching the speed of light?

a) If not: How do you calculate the difference in velocities of objects you see around you with acceleration $a$ for proper time duration $\Delta t$ with initial velocity $v$?

b) If so: You are moving at $c-10m/s$, what happens when you put on your jets and accelerate at 10 $m/s^2$ for another 2 seconds in your proper time?

Edit:
I understand intuitively why an observer cannot see another object accelerate to c. Because as the object approaches the speed of light, the electromagnetic forces will start to take forever to transfer energy from particle to particle in the observer's frame, making it impossible for the object to reach the speed of light. As $v \rightarrow c$ the acceleration $a \rightarrow 0$.

I am trying to understand what physically prevents this from happening when you are the observer accelerating like in b). In all inertial reference frames and for all reference frames with the same acceleration, the laws of physics are the same. So regardless of your initial velocity, in *your own* frame, accelerating yourself another $10m/s$ should takes the same amount of time and energy when you are stationary as when you are moving at $c-10m/s$.

Comment: The relationship between acceleration and velocity is still that of a derivative so the usual relationship $v = u + a t$ continues to hold. However, it becomes infinitely harder to maintain constant acceleration as you go closer to the speed of light (note that in special relativity, $F \neq m a$).

Comment: There is [a sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_motion_(relativity)) in which you can have constant acceleration indefinitely without reaching $c$.

Comment: That Wikipedia page is about the hyperbolic motion of objects with constant proper acceleration "graphed on a Minkowski diagram whose coordinates represent a suitable inertial (non-accelerated) frame". I'm looking from the perspective of an observer inside the accelerated frame where would he encounter problems reaching c

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between acceleration and velocity is the same in special relativity (SR) as it is in Newtonian mechanics (NM),
$$
a = \frac{dv}{dt}.
$$
However, it becomes infinitely harder to maintain a constant acceleration as the speed approaches closer to the speed of light.

Let us see this in equations. Imagine an object starts at rest at $t=0$ and is acted upon by a constant force $F$ forever. We have
\begin{align}
F &= m \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{v}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} \right) \qquad \text{(SR)} \tag{1} \\
&= m \frac{d}{dt} v \qquad \text{(NM)} \tag{2}
\end{align}
I'm doing both SR and NM so you can see the difference. Solving these differential equations, we find
\begin{align}
v(t) &= \frac{F}{m} \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+F^2t^2/(m^2c^2) }} \qquad \text{(SR)} \tag{3} \\
&= \frac{F}{m} t \qquad \text{(NM)} \tag{4}
\end{align}
The acceleration in each case is
\begin{align}
a(t) &= \frac{F}{m} \frac{1}{ [1 +F^2t^2/(m^2c^2) ]^{3/2}} \qquad \text{(SR)} \tag{5} \\
&= \frac{F}{m}  \qquad \text{(NM)} \tag{6}
\end{align}
Based on these formulas, we can make the following comments:

1. In NM, constant force means constant acceleration (from (6)). In SR, this is not true (from (5)).
2. As time passes on (i.e. as $t \to \infty$), $a(t) \to F/m$ in NM, but $a(t) \to 0$ in SR. In other words, even though we are still applying a constant force, the acceleration goes to zero in SR.
3. In SR, the velocity is ALWAYS less than $c$. Furthermore, as $t \to \infty$, we have $v(t) \to c$ but it can never cross this value. In NM, the velocity grows unboundedly and there is no speed limit.
4. For small values of $t$, when the speed of the body is still small compared to the speed of light, the SR and NM formulas are identical, since
   \begin{align}
   v(t)|_{\text{SR}} &\stackrel{t\approx 0}{=} \frac{F}{m} t + {\mathcal O}(t^3) \approx v(t)|_{\text{NM}} , \\
   a(t)|_{\text{SR}} &\stackrel{t\approx 0}{=} \frac{F}{m}  + {\mathcal O}(t^2) \approx a(t)|_{\text{NM}} , 
   \end{align}

Comment: Re, "It becomes infinitely harder to maintain a constant acceleration as the speed approaches closer to the speed of light." That would depend on whether you are talking about the acceleration of an object as seen by a "stationary" observer, or whether you are talking about the _proper_ acceleration (e.g., as felt by passengers on board a space ship.) If your space ship has a magic "reactionless" drive (so that accelerating does not change the intrinsic mass of the ship,) then the amount of "thrust" needed to maintain a given proper acceleration (e.g., 9.8 m/s^2) never changes.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are accelerating at a constant rate of 10 m/s2, will you see things around you move at 10 m/s faster every second, even when approaching the speed of light?

> a) If not: How do you calculate the difference in velocities of objects you see around you with acceleration a for proper time duration Δt with initial velocity v?

If initial velocity is zero then velocity change =  $   at\over \sqrt{1 + (at/c)^2} $

That is from this page: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html

If initial velocity is not zero then we add initial velocity and velocity change using relativistic velocity addition, which is
$\dfrac{v + u}{1 + \dfrac{vu}{c^2}}$

In the above "velocity change" means the velocity change that acceleration $a$ causes in time $t$ if there is no initial velocity. $a$ is proper acceleration.

Oh yes, I would say that this is rubbish:

> I understand intuitively why an observer cannot see another object accelerate to c. Because as the object approaches the speed of light, the electromagnetic forces will start to take forever to transfer energy from particle to particle in the observer's frame, making it impossible for the object to reach the speed of light.

Comment: That first equation you refer to is calculating v, which is the velocity as seen from earths frame. I'm looking to understand where the observers in the space ship will encounter issues accelerating, as explained from their own frame of reference.

Comment: "Oh yes, I would say that this is rubbish:" I would appreciate if you could elaborate. The following video explains that idea although it is not where I first got the idea:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vitf8YaVXhc&ab_channel=FloatHeadPhysics

Comment: @Zach I have seen the video before, and I thought then "what rubbish" or something similar. Everybody in the comments section thinks it's great. So I guess I just don't understand.

Comment: "Velocity seen in ship's fame is -v then" that would be practically like observer watching another fall into a black hole and saying the same... In one frame the observer is taking infinite time to cross the event horizon (reach c in this example), but the other observer's proper time it's completely different.

Comment: @Zach Oh, v is ship's velocity seen in earth's frame. Ships velocity seen in ship's fame is also v then. Dude looks out of ship window and sees that earth moves at -v, so  dude says ships velocity is v.

Answer (score 0):

> You are moving at c−10m/s, what happens when you put on your jets and accelerate at 10 m/s2 for another 2 seconds in your proper time?

What moving at great speed means, is that when you look out of your vehicle's window, you see the world passing by at great speed.

When world is passing by at great speed, it is very hard to accelerate the world. World can never reach velocity c.

In the above "accelerating the world" means pushing the gas pedal of your vehicle. That does cause an acceleration of the world, as we know from experience.

If, according to you, moving at great speed does not mean that when you look out of the vehicle's window, you see the world passing by at great speed, then please tell me what moving at great speed means, so that I can answer the question about moving at great speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your speed by some amount S relative to one frame, then relative to another the change in your speed is given by the relativistic velocity addition formula, so it could be more or less than S. Suppose the Earth is travelling just a millimetre-per-second less than c relative to some frame, you can get into your car and accelerate to 50 meters per second relative to objects on the Earth, but relative to the other frame your speed will hardly have changed at all.

Comment: If you have observer A and B moving at velocity v relative to each other, they will each see the other moving at the same speed, always. It's a very fundamental concept of SR. The distance they perceive to be from one another may (and probably will) be different. Relativistic velocity addition formula is used when an observer for example throws something at some velocity x in his own frame. The other observer will see the additional speed of the thrown object to be lower.

Comment: Response to part 2 of your answer:
We encounter the same issue here as in my scenario with the spaceship. If you are looking at the car from a frame looking at the planet moving at c-1 mm/s, it will take an infinite amount of time from that frame for the car to accelerate even 1 mm/s, but takes finite time in the car's frame.